# How can I maintain reference to the right object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, socket.io

I have code like this:

```
for (var index = 1; index < args.length; index++) {
    var shell = args[index];
    listener.of('/' + shell.namespace || 'shotgun')
        .on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.on('execute', function (cmdStr, context, options) {
                console.log('Received: ' + cmdStr);
                var result = shell.execute(cmdStr, context, options);
                socket.emit('result', result);
            });
        });
}
```

I'm using [socket.io](http://socket.io) and I'm creating multiple namespaces. The socket.io namespaces are working great, but in the `execute` callback the reference to `shell` is always the last object created in the for loop. I need each iteration of the loop to keep reference to the `shell` from that iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the eventual answer will be to use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) (ECMAScript 6 or [`node --harmony`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13351965)):

```
for (let index = 1; index < args.length; index++) {
    let shell = args[index];
    // ...
}
```

In the meantime, you can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), or an additional `function` scope, to *keep* a different `index` and `shell` for each iteration:

```
function iterator(shell, index) {
    listener.of('/' + shell.namespace || 'shotgun')
        // ...
}

for (var index = 1; index < args.length; index++) {
    iterator(args[index], index);
}
```

And, if `args` is an `Array`, this can also be done with [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
args.forEach(function (shell, index) {
    listener.of('/' + shell.namespace || 'shotgun')
        // ...
});
```

Comment: Totally forgot about `.forEach` and how it provides a proper closure. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the solutions for your challenge using `.bind`.

```
for (var index = 1; index < args.length; index++) {
  var shell = args[index];
  listener.of('/' + shell.namespace || 'shotgun')
    .on('connection', function(socket) {
      shell = this.shell;
      socket.on('execute', function (cmdStr, context, options) {
        console.log('Received: ' + cmdStr);
        var result = shell.execute(cmdStr, context, options);
        socket.emit('result', result);
      });
    }.bind({ shell: shell }));
}
```

Comment: Very clever. Very clever indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating a closure that references the variable `shell` and evaluates the variable when the function is called, not when it is defined. You need to create a closure that references the current value of the loop variable. There are several ways, but one is to use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
for (var index = 1; index < args.length; index++) {
    var shell = args[index];
    listener.of('/' + shell.namespace || 'shotgun')
        .on('connection', (function (_shell) { return function (socket) {
            socket.on('execute', function (cmdStr, context, options) {
                console.log('Received: ' + cmdStr);
                var result = _shell.execute(cmdStr, context, options);
                socket.emit('result', result);
            }; }(shell)));
        });
}
```

Note: You could use the same name (`shell`) for the formal argument to the IIFE, which would hide the variable in the outer scope, but I renamed it `_shell` to clarify what's going on.