# AWS Lambda exports class works in node.js v6.4 but not in node.js v4.3, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have code works in node.js v6.4:
just two files, index.js:

```
  // ------------ Index.js ------------ 
  'use strict';

  var Event = require('./models/event.js');

  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     console.log('done');
  }
```

and event.js:

```
  // ------------ Event.js ------------ 

  class Event {
    static get dynamoDBTableName() {
      return
    }
    get hashValue() {
      return
    }
    parseReference(reference) {
      return
    }
  }

  exports.Event = Event
```

when run `index.handler` on AWS Lambda which use version node.js 4.3, it throws a error:

```
  Syntax error in module 'index': SyntaxError
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:16:13)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

I think it's something wrong with `exports.Event = Event`,

Is there some trick to fix this.

I'm new to node.js.

Any help should be appreciated.

I think it's not SyntaxError with `(event, context, callback) => { }`

Because AWS Lambda sample code runs well with this Syntax:

[image]

Comment: The OP updated the original question, and (rightly) added that the arrow function was not the culprit. My mistake, I gave a wrong answer below and thereby misled the community into marking the question as duplicate. I think this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I originally thought the arrow function was the culprit. However, AWS Node.js 4.3.2 DOES support the arrow function, as mentioned in this [post about Node.js 4.3.2 Runtime on Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-4-3-2-runtime-now-available-on-lambda/).

---

### NEW (correct) ANSWER

Does the **event.js** file start with `'use strict';`?

You must use strict mode for a class declaration in node.js 4.3.2

[Mozilla Developer Network about strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Hoping this will help...

---

### ORIGINAL (incorrect) ANSWER

module.exports = Products

I believe the arrow function:

```
() => {}
```

is not yet implemented in the nodejs version you are using (4.3).

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644341/node-js-support-for-function-keyword-alias/38241325#38241325)

Arrow functions are supported in Node.js since version 4.4.5

---

If updating your nodejs version is not an option for you, you could replace:

```
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('done');
  }
```

with

```
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) = function() {
     console.log('done');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for rapid response , but sorry this may not help. After change to `function(event, context, callback) {...}` , Same error throw again.

Comment: @beeth0ven you are right, it seems arrow functions are available in AWS Nodejs 4.3: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-4-3-2-runtime-now-available-on-lambda/ My answer is therefore wrong, and your question may not be a duplicate; I would delete my answer, but then these comments would be gone, wouldn't they?

Comment: After test code on node v5.1.1, It's throws error `SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`, So I add `'use strict'` to file event.js. Then it works.Thanks for giving me the important information. Could you please update answer to: " just add  use strict to file event.js`. And I will mark your answer as correct.Thanks.

Comment: Glad the issue is fixed :)