# AWS Lambda exports class not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am using NodeJs 6.10.2. I am using 2 files

**index.js**

```
var operation = require('./Handler/opHandler').opHandler;

var lambdaHandler = function () {
    var o = new operation();
    o.deleteMessage();
}

exports.lambdaHandler = function(event, context, callback) {
    handleSQSMessages(context, callback);
};
```

**opHandler.js**

```
opHandler = function() {
     this.db = '';
}
opHandler.prototype.deleteMessage = function (receiptHandle, callback) {
    // My code here
    // this.db = 'new val';
}

exports.opHandler = opHandler;
```

when run index.lambdaHandler on AWS Lambda with NodeJs 6.10, following error occurs

```
 Syntax error in module 'index': SyntaxError
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:16:13)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

I have googled and found similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331059/aws-lambda-exports-class-works-in-node-js-v6-4-but-not-in-node-js-v4-3-how-to-f) but according to it above code should work in NodeJs 6.10

Comment: please paste the full code that you used

Answer (score 1):

Try another method or module export. It should work in your case.

**index.js**

```
var operation = require('./Handler/opHandler');

var lambdaHandler = function () {
    var o = new operation();
    o.deleteMessage();
}

exports.lambdaHandler = function(event, context, callback) {
    handleSQSMessages(context, callback);
};
```

**opHandler.js**

```
opHandler = function() {
     this.db = '';
}
opHandler.prototype.deleteMessage = function (receiptHandle, callback) {
    // My code here
    // this.db = 'new val';
}

module.exports = opHandler;
```

It solved my issue may help you out.