# Typings: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

When running a typings command I always get the error:

```
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\strip-bom\index.js:2
module.exports = x => {
                   ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\typings-core\dist\utils\fs.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

So far I tried reinstalling typings (v 2.0.0), `npm cache clean` and all that, but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I have the same issue.. did you manage to find a solution  to this?

Comment: turns out that upgrading my node.js version solved this for me.. node = new version-hell?

Comment: How is running an outdated version of software a "version-hell"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js support for => ('function' keyword alias)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644341/node-js-support-for-function-keyword-alias)

Answer (score 0):

Under windows, I got node version 0.12, uninstalled it, reinstalled the versoin 6.9.x. Problem got solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just install the new version of node from [node page](https://nodejs.org/en/), there is no need of uninstalled it first because the binary files are overwritten.