# node typings Unexpected token =>

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to nodejs and try to install `typings` globally to make intellisense available for a few modules by using

```
npm install -g typings
```

After this command I try to use:

```
typings search tape
```

which gives me

```
C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\typings-core\node_modules\strip-bom\index.js:2
module.exports = x => {
                   ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\node_modules\typings-core\node_modules\jspm-config\dist\es5\utils\fs.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: node -v -> v0.12.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js support for => ('function' keyword alias)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644341/node-js-support-for-function-keyword-alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Node is outdated. The module you are trying to load uses arrow functions, which is a syntax that was first partially introduced in Node v4.0.

Note that Node v0.12 went out of long-term support in December 2016, so is no longer supported at all. In addition, many Node modules require Node v4.0 or later, exactly because this version introduced a lot of new features that are not available in earlier versions.

I would recommend that you upgrade to Node v6.9 (current LTS version) or Node v7.4 (current stable version).

Comment: Our corporate PCs have this version installed so it's not possible for me to upgrade it unfortunately. I will try to install older version of typings then. Or try to use tsd maybe..,