# Node.js:Syntax Error Missing after arguments list

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I am trying to set very basic local host.

My code:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I get an error:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

Syntax Error missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: what version of node are you using

Comment: May be you are getting an error because of the arrow function. The arrow functions are not supported in the older versions of node.js

Comment: i am usig version 3.3.1

Comment: Arrow function support started at version 4.0 and was fully fleshed out starting in 4.4.5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38241325/37168. Time to upgrade your Node installation!