# Define a function in nodejs without "function" keyword can't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I try to use the AWS client scan the dynamoDB table.

I define a function as

```
var scan = (err, data) =>{}
```

this couldn't work
but when I write

```
function scan (err, data){}
```

this work fine.

I don't understand why when I define the function with the arrow expression couldn't work, even inside the function, when I use forEach() or promise it all work fine in the same script.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - were you seeing an error of some sort?  Does your function perhaps make use of `this` within it?

Comment: Probably you are using older version of NodeJS, try to use 6+, will work

Comment: Might be your version of `Node.js`. [`Arrow function` support wasn't introduced until `v4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38241325/5566355)

Comment: The function that is working is a syntax of ES6, You must be running with the old version of Node.js which doesn't support ES6 features, Try using latest Node.js or try using a transpiler like babel or something.

Answer (score 0):

**var nameOfTheFunction = (parameters) => { //code here }**