# Non capturing branch reset regex in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, regex, regex-group

https://regex101.com/r/UXnhTy/1

```
var date = /(?|(Sat)ur|(Sun))day/;

console.log(date.exec("Sunday"));
```

This fails with:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?|(Sat)ur|(Sun))day/: Invalid group
```

Is there a version of NodeJS that supports this?  Or some library out there that

I tested this with nodejs v8.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. An advanced alternative regex library for JavaScript is [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com), but it doesn't have the feature you're after - not even as an [addon](http://xregexp.com/plugins/).
A simpler regex feature that is supported by XRegExp is [named capture groups](http://xregexp.com/syntax/), so you can write:

```
var days = XRegExp('(?:(?<d>Sat)ur|(?<d>Sun))day', 'gi');
```

You can't use numbers as group names, but named groups should fit what your needs - they allow backreferences (using `\k<d>`), replacement (`${d}`), capturing (`match.d`), and all features of a regular numbered group.

Named captured groups is supported natively by ES2018: [ES2018 Regular Expression Updates](http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/es2018-regular-expression-updates-an-opinionated-summary/).
According to [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-named-capture-groups), named capture groups are supported by Node.js ≥10.3.0, or by  ≥8.6.0 with the [`--harmony` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13351965/7586).

Comment: You can't use identically named capturing groups in JavaScript RegExp, that pattern of yours throws a "*`Duplicate capture group name`*" exception. `XRegExp` also throws "*`Cannot use same name for multiple groups`*".